# modifying parameter prior to method invocation

Tags: java, parameters, annotations, parameter-passing, java-6

I have a parameter called "server" in several methods:

```
public synchronized Client getClientByStreamId(String streamId, Server server) {
  //some logic
}

public Client getClientByPublicSID(String publicSID, boolean isAVClient, Server server) {
  //some logic
}
```

What I want is that everytime those methods are called there is a check, that is performed to the param server *before* the method is called:

```
if (server == null) {
  server = someServer; //someServer is a variable I get somewhere else
}
```

From what I know there must be some trick with an annotation in Java6 so that you can do something like (pseudo code):

```
@ManipulateArgs(MyMethod);
public synchronized Client getClientByStreamId(String streamId, Server server) {
  //some logic
}

@ManipulateArgs(MyMethod);
public Client getClientByPublicSID(String publicSID, boolean isAVClient, Server server) {
  //some logic
}

private MyMethod(Server server) {
  if (server == null) {
    server = someServer; //someServer is a variable I get somewhere else
  }
}
```

Some kind of "pre-processor" that is called *before* the actual method is invoked with the params.
I just can't remember what the name of this pre-processing was. Or if it was annotaction based or something else. But I think it was an annotation.

Thanks
Sebastian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general term of what you're looking for is a *method interceptor*. There are a variety of ways they are implemented. Aspect oriented programming is one way. See the tutorial http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-01-2002/jw-0118-aspect.html. If you're using a framework such as Spring or JBoss, there are interceptor annotations built in.

Comment: You are right. Method interceptor, that was exactly the term I was searching for. But it seems like I would need a dynamic one as I would like to modify/manipulate this argument on each method call. And that seems to be very resource hungry as there is a string comparison involved in the Interceptor/Annotate method, to map the method name to the right interceptor. I guess I will rather do it with some Decorator pattern.

Comment: If you wanted to you could write an annotation processor that modified the byte code at compile time.